# Minimum amount before obligation of Challah

Tags: halacha, bread, challah-shabbat-bread, separating-challah, maseches-challa

How much bread does one have to be baking for it to be obligated in Challah? Does it depend Ashkenazi  vs. Sephardic? Sources much appreciated please.

Comment: How did you try to figure out the answer to this question before asking it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different opinions. Since you asked for sources, here are a collection of them.

---

[According to Halachipedia](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Challah&oldid=32234), there are some differences. It reads:

### Ashkenazim custom

> According to Ashkenazim, some say that the Minhag is to remove Challah with a Bracha when making a dough with 5 pounds (2.27 kg) or more of flour and remove Challah without a Bracha when making dough with 3 pounds (1.35 kg) or more of flour.<sub>11</sub> Others say that the Minhag of Yerushalyim is to take Challah off without a Bracha if the flour is 2.65 pounds (1200 grams) or more and to remove Challah with a Bracha if the flour is 3.67 pounds (1666 grams) or more.<sub>12</sub>

---

<sub>11</sub> Shulchan Aruch YD 324:1 and Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 35:1 write that the amount necessary in order to be obligated in Challah is 43.2 KeBaytzim of flour.

<sub>12</sub> Halichot Shlomo (Moadim vol 2 pg 338 note 54) writes that this was the Minhag in Rav Shlomo Zalman’s house and that of Yerushalyim. Middot Vshiurei Torah p. 232 (Rav Chaim Beinish) agrees that this is the minhag Yerushalayim to take challah with a bracha for 3.67 pounds. Shevet Halevi 11:253:3 holds that the minhag in Yerushalayim is to take challah with a bracha for 1.75kg (3.86lb) of flour. Rav Elyashiv (Haarot Pesachim 48b) also said the minhag Yerushalayim is like Rav Chaim Noeh for taking off challah with a bracha and to separate without a bracha for 1 kg. However, Steipler in Shiurin Shel Torah (5716, p. 86) writes that one should take off challah without a bracha for flour of a bit more than 1200 grams, like Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach. A bracha is only recited if using more than 2.25 kg of flour, like Rav Henkin.

### Sephardic custom

According to some Sephardim, one should take off Challah with a Bracha when making a dough with 3.44 pounds (1560 grams) or more of flour and it is a pious practice to remove Challah without a Bracha when making a dough with 2.65 pounds (1200 grams) or more of flour. <sub>13</sub>

However, some say that one should only remove Challah with a Bracha for flour that is 5.14 pounds (2332 grams) and without a Bracha for flour that is 3.67 pounds (1666 grams).<sub>14</sub>

---

<sub>13</sub> Yalkut Yosef YD 324:6. Rav David Yosef and Rav Yitzchak Yosef (approbation to Hidurei Hamidot p. 78, second edition) agreed with Rav Hadar Margoliyat that the dirham of the Rambam was approximately 2.8 grams. Accordingly, the shiur challah would be 520 dirhams * (2.8 g / 1 dirham) = 1.456 kg = 3.21 lb.

<sub>14</sub> Ben Ish Hai, Halachot 2nd Year, Shemini 21 writes that the shiur of Challah is 777 dirhams or 5.14 pounds (using 3 grams per dirham). Rav Mordechai Eliyahu (comments on Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 35:2) holds 5.29lbs and without a bracha for 3.67lbs.

Also, refer to [here](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/baking-challahs-for-shabbos/).

Comment: This is kinda misleading. Everyone agrees you take challa iff there is 42.5 eggs' volume of flour. All these opinions are just different people's estimations of an egg's size.

Comment: Thanks very much @shmuel great work

Comment: No problem. Here to help! Thanks for the great questions! Keep shteiging!